# Null-valued expression for script on WSUS?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to retrieve a list of updates in the scope. My code is as follows:

```
#Loads Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration assembly in order to connect to the WSUS server
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration”) | Out-Null

#Make the initial WSUS connection by using the .NET accelerator     [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy] and the static method getUpdateServer(), which requires two values: the WSUS server name and a Boolean value for a secure connection.
$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer()

#Creating the Computer Target Scope object
$computerscope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope

#Find all clients using the computer target scope
$wsus.GetComputerTargets($computerscope)

#Gets computer status
$Wsus.GetComputerStatus($computerscope,[Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateSources]::All)
```

When I try to run the following:

```
#Provides a summary of whether the clients that are specified in the scope require the update
ForEach($update in $computerscope)
{
    $update = $wsus.SearchUpdates($computerscope)
}

$update[0].GetSummary($computerscope)
```

I receive the following error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:6 char:1
+ $update[0].GetSummary($computerscope)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

even though I am passing `$computerscope` in the `GetSummary` method.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The variable `$update` defined in the loop is not an array. Perhaps you wanted to loop over all computers you get with `$wsus.GetComputerTargets($computerscope)` ?

Comment: @Theo Yes that was my intention.